# How to replace all tab characters in a file by sequences of white-spaces in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, code-formatting

Given a file in my project, I want to be able to replace all of the tab characters in the file with white spaces. Is there any way to do this in intellij?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Go to  Edit | Convert Indents , and then choose To Spaces or To Tabs respectively. It's in  the documentation: [Changing identation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/changing-indentation.html)

Comment: Do you think it's possible to replace tabs with spaces in all files of a project? When I close all my files, the options To Spaces and To Tabs become inactive

Comment: Note that this only converts the tabs at the start of a line. Tabs in the middle of a line (between other text) are not touched.

Answer (score 61):

#### Replace only tabs used for indentation

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- type "To Spaces" > Enter

  [image: To Spaces]

#### Replace all tabs

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- check Regex
- Enter \t and spaces
- Replace all

  [image: Replace tab with 4 spaces]

Comment: Note that your search and replace (ctrl-r) will always convert a tab to a fixed number of spaces. It does not do a tabulation where you can line things up from one line to the next by using a tab. The indention trick, however, does indeed line things up.

Comment: Replace ```Ctrl``` with ```Cmd``` for Mac and works on IntelliJ 2018.3

Comment: It seems clion is lacking in this area a bit. While it's true that using a regex conversion doesn't keep things aligned properly, it appears to be the ONLY way to ensure there are no tabs left in the file.