# IntelliJ doesn't use tab

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I build using Intellij, I don't get any errors. When I compile using maven, I get the following errors:

```
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\config\KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:57: error: Indent must use tab characters
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\config\KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:57: error: Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only.
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\config\KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:72: error: Indent must use tab characters
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\config\KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:72: error: Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only.
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\config\KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:85: error: Indent must use tab characters
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\config\KinesisBinderConfiguration.java:85: error: Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only.
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:78: error: Indent must use tab characters
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:78: error: Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only.
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:79: error: Indent must use tab characters
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:79: error: Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only.
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:106: error: Indent must use tab characters
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:106: error: Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only.
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:128: error: Indent must use tab characters
C:\GIT\spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis\spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis\src\main\java\org\springframework\cloud\stream\binder\kinesis\KinesisMessageChannelBinder.java:128: error: Line has leading space characters; indentation should be performed with tabs only.
```

[image]

Comment: If you make the one of the reversed actions from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47464401/3885376 is that Maven plugin ok with this?

Comment: You need to go into the files listed in your error message and reformat them.